# Prove the increasing union of ideals is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

prove that $I_{1} \subseteq I_{2} \subseteq I_{3} \subseteq....$ are ideals of $R$ then $\bigcup_{n =1} I_n$ is an ideal of $R$. I am having a hard time picture this in my mind. Help anyone.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of an ideal is?

Comment: The idea is this: any pair of elements in the union must be in a common $I_k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \cdots$ be an ascending chain of ideals in a ring $R$. Define $I = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty I_n$. We first show that $I$ is an additive abelian group:

1. Let $x, y \in I$, then $x \in I_m$, $y \in I_n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb N$. Since we are in an ascending chain of ideals, either $I_m \subseteq I_n$ or $I_n \subseteq I_m$. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $I_m \subseteq I_n$, then $x, y \in I_n$. Since $I_n$ is an ideal, it is an additive abelian group, and in particular it is closed under addition, that is, $x + y = y + x \in I_n$. Hence $x + y \in I$ and we also get that $I$ is commutative under addition.
2. Let $x \in I$, then $x \in I_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. Since $I_n$ is an ideal, it is an additive group, so $-x \in I_n$. Thus $-x \in I$.
3. Observe that $0 \in I$ since $0 \in I_1$ and $I_1$ is an ideal and hence additive abelian group, so it has an additive identity: $0$.

Now we show that $I$ absorbs elements from $R$. Since we are working in a commutative ring with identity, we don't have to worry about left and right ideals. Let $d \in R$ and $i \in I$ be arbitrary. Since $i \in I$, then $i \in I_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. Since $I_n$ is an ideal, it has the absorption property, so $id \in I_n$ and hence $id \in I$. Conclude by definition that $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: Thanks man i had a feeling the answer will be like that but i could not comprehend the ascending order of the chain. Thanks

Comment: The ascending chain is **key** here. The union of to ideals is not in general an ideal. (Make sure you can come up with a quick example of why that's true, say in $\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: Yeah that is what i realize at first that is one of the reason i post the questions. Since you show me that the key was the ascending everything make perfect sense man. Yeah i am working on the example right now. I was think on using mod z